# How to Convert Nested array to Value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

My arrays

```
a:3:{s:6:"Choice";a:2:{i:0;s:5:"First";i:1;s:6:"Second";}s:5:"fcode";s:26:"form_rajas_exmsw2rpc81anlj";s:9:"useremail";s:26:"rajasekarang.cud@gmail.com";}

array (
  'Choice' => 
  array (
    0 => 'First',
    1 => 'Second',
  ),
  'fcode' => 'form_rajas_exmsw2rpc81anlj',
  'useremail' => 'rajasekarang.cud@gmail.com',
)
```

my php code

```
$arrays = 'a:3:{s:6:"Choice";a:2:{i:0;s:5:"First";i:1;s:6:"Second";}s:5:"fcode";s:26:"form_rajas_exmsw2rpc81anlj";s:9:"useremail";s:26:"rajasekarang.cud@gmail.com";}';

$decode = unserialize($arrays);
foreach($decode as $key => $value) {
    echo '<td width="100">' . $value . '</td>';
}
```

My Error is :

> **Notice:** Array to string conversion in....

The first Values in Nested Array.

How to convert nested array as a Value?

I need to show like this,

`<tr><td>First,Second</td><td>form_rajas_exmsw2rpc81anlj</td><td>rajasekarang.cud@gmail.com</td></tr>`

Comment: The first Values in Nested Array there is 2 value which are "first" and "second" which you wanna show?

Comment: There are many ways to convert nested array as a Value. What is the expected output ? So we can suggest accordingly

Comment: I Need To Show All values..

Comment: I Need To Show All values dynamically.

Comment: There is an edit button. Most easy answear is to use `echo '<pre>'; print_r( $decode ); echo '</pre>';`. You can also make a `recursion function` that checks if the input is an array: ifso recall itself with that array, else print the string.

Answer (score 1):

If `$value` is an array, you need a nested loop.

```
foreach ($decode as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        $value = array($valule);
    }
    foreach ($value as $subvalue) {
        echo "<td width='100'>$subvalue</td>";
    }
}
```

If you can have multiple levels of nesting, you should write a recursive function that handles each level.

If you want a sub-array to be shown as a comma-separated list, you can use `implode`.

```
foreach ($decode as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $value = implode(', ', $value);
    }
    echo "<td width='100'>$subvalue</td>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, The Results is <td width='100'>First</td><td> Second</td> But I Need <td width='100'>First, Second</td> It is Possible?

Comment: Use `implode` for that.

Comment: It Works $decode = unserialize($arrays);
     echo'<table><tr>';
     foreach ($decode as $key => $value) {
      
      if (!is_array($value)) {
       $value = array($value);
      }
      
      if (is_array($value)) {
       $value = implode(', ', $value);
      }
      echo "<td width='100'>$value</td>";
     }
     echo'</tr></table>';

Comment: You don't need the first `$value = array($value)` any more.

Comment: I change That,      $decode = unserialize($arrays);
     echo'<table><tr>';
     foreach ($decode as $key => $value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
       $value = implode(', ', $value);
      }
      echo "<td width='100'>$value</td>";
     }
     echo'</tr></table>';

Answer (score 0):

you have nested array populated with elements of diferent size so you will always get an error. so in your foreach loop, you can check if the value is an array or not, like for instance

```
if (count($value)>1){
//code here like for instance echo $value[0]...
}//not recomended becuse an array can have only one value, but you can if you know you will put at least 2
```

or

```
if(is_array($value)..
```

Me I will do the following:

```
foreach($thing as $thingy =>$that){
   //check if array or not
   if(is_array($that)){
       foreach($that as $t)
             //do whatever
   }else
      //do whatever
}
```